# JQuery function not finding checked on initial getJSON load

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have a function to calculate the values associated with checkboxes. After the `#QuoteTypeID` element is changed, All of the checkboxes and values are loaded in with a `getJSON` call in the function `LoadOptionsAndMore()`. Then the function `CalcualatePrice()` is called but it does not find any of the checkboxes which are checked even though there are a few that are checked.

The next time that the function is called, it does find all of the checkboxes that are checked.

How do I get around this?

```
$("#QuoteTypeId").change(function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
  LoadLegalAndDincluded(val);
  $("#QuoteTypeId option[value='0']").remove();
  LoadOptionsAndMore();
  CalculatePrice();
});

function LoadOptionsAndMore() {
  ...
  // loads all of the checkboxes with a few selected
}

function CalculatePrice() {
  var ttl = 0.0;
  $('[id^=WorksheetRow-]:checked').each(function () {
    ttl += $('#WSPrice-' + $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop()).text().split('$').pop() * 1.00; 
  });

  $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ttl);
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to get elements that do not exist yet, due to calling an asynchronous method that creates them.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the `getJSON` and used a regular `ajax` with `async: false`

Comment: FYI, async false has been removed from jQuery 3X and is also being deprecated by browsers.  You should avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks again for leading me in the right direction. I added `.done()` to the  call and removed the deprecated warning that was popping up.

Comment: very nice.  good job!